# JRadioButton border/padding/insets/margin... whatever you call it

Tags: java, swing, radio-button, jradiobutton

In my Java app I am trying to create a very simple form with a label and a set of controls on each row of the form. Imagine something like this crude ASCII diagram:

```
   Result 1: (*) pass  ( ) fail
   Result 2: ( ) pass  (*) fail
Error Count: [10______]
Explanation: [Operator overload___]
```

Annoyingly the `JRadioButton`s don't line up with the rest of the controls as they have a large amount of padding all around, pushing them to the right a couple of pixels and adding a lot of space between lines. I end up with something like this:

```
   Result 1:   (*) pass  ( ) fail

   Result 2:   ( ) pass  (*) fail

Error Count: [10______]
Explanation: [Operator overload___]
```

How can I get the radio buttons to stop having so much empty space so they can line up nicely with everything else? If it matters this is using the GTK L&F; I haven't tried running the program under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like there are two culprits:

1. The mini-`JPanel` containing the two radio buttons has a `FlowLayout` which defaults to adding 5 pixels of padding around each component.
2. Doing `radioButton.setBorder(null)` eliminates another pixel's worth of space around the buttons. It also screws up the dotted line drawn around them when they have focus, though.

Comment: flowlayout is generally poor on anything but lists of buttons (of the typical "Cancel" "Accept" variety)

Comment: And it's no good on buttons because it gives them variable size - very untidy looking; a grid layout is better for buttons.  Flow layout is pretty much useless.

Comment: You are right -- there is a 1px difference between Accept vs Cancel buttons in a FlowLayout on my platform. On the other hand, it centers and spaces things nicely, which your typical grid layout does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GridBagLayout, and make sure to anchor cells (each label and checkbox would have its own cell) towards the left or towards the right as needed. The labels would be right-justified, the checkboxes would be left-justified.

Since customizing GridBagLayouts by hand is a hassle, I recommend using the NetBeans GUI builder and adjusting them using its graphical "customize" tool.

Comment: Bad advice; use a table-based layout for things where GridBag may be the only other alternative.  There are a number of good table-based layout available on the net for free.

Comment: GridBag *is* table-based, and the poster is clearly looking for something table-like. Yes, others may be easier to use, but this one is included with the JDK and allows a great level of control over the results.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution can be to change margin (radionbuttons's setMargin method). This should do the job. The only downside is that margins/insets will be different for different LAFs.